# error in grunt-saas, even though saas is installed?

Tags: gruntjs, rubygems, saas, node-sass, grunt-sass-lint

I am using Mac OSX. 
**gem install saas** is done.
**ruby** is also update.
still show **Warning: spawn sass ENOENT** 
Couldn't understand why?

Answer (score 1):

have you updated your xcode?

Here's what worked for me. From "iamcubcs"

https://github.com/oklai/koala/issues/679

1. Open Terminal
2. Install Homebrew:   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
3. Do not close Terminal, open Mac Appstore and check Update, install all XCode Command Line Tools updates OR in my case, XCode Command Line Tools started install automaticly throught Terminal right after step 2.
4. Back to Terminal
5. Install Ruby:   brew install rbenv ruby-build
6. Install SASS gem:   sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass